# insert into mysql using loop pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo, foreach

i have  a table in mysql having field seat_id(pk),bus_id,seat_number,row_name,col_name

now i have to insert value into each field from this php code.

```
<?php
  for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            for($j=1;$j<=4;$j++)
            {
                echo "<td>
                <input type=\"text\" value=\"\" style=\"width:20px\" name=\"seat_no[]\" />
                <input type=\"text\" style=\"width:20px\" value=\"$i\" name=\"row_name[]\" />
                <input type=\"text\" value=\"$j\" style=\"width:20px\" name=\"col_name[]\" />
                </td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
  ?>
```

now problem is that how to loop for each row to insert into mysql.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is PDO here and what is the problem? You want to insert values, but there are no values. It's year 2015. - please, communicate. It's not like we have to use smoke signals to send each other information.

Comment: <!-----$val=$_POST['seat_no'];
 foreach($val as $value)
 {
  $q="Insert into bus_seat_assign (bus_id,seat_number,row_name,col_name) values ('1','$val','','')";
  $stmt=$dbh->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute();
  
 }------>

Comment: I have no words.. you're asking for help but you sure are not making it easy. Good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (bus_id, seat_number,row_name,col_name) VALUES
(203, 5,'something','something'),
(203, 4,'something','something'),
(203, 7,'something','something');
```

Comment: can you paste array values here?

Answer (score 0):

!@Suraj i have to inert this table...
INSERT INTO table_name (bus_id, seat_number,row_name,col_name) VALUES
(203, 1,'1','1'),(203, 2,'1','2'),(203, 3,'1','3'),(203, 4,'1','4') 1st row...and so on....